# MaterialDesign XAML Transitioner Binding ItemsSource and ItemTemplate like in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, material-design, material-design-in-xaml

I have a control called NewScaleRangeCalibrationControl and a viewmodel for that control called NewScaleRangeCalibrationControlViewModel. Now, I want to display a list of that controls in the other window called NewScaleCalibrationDialog (and it's viewmodel NewScaleCalibrationDialogViewModel). In NewScaleCalibrationDialogViewModel I have an

`ICollection<NewScaleRangeCalibrationControlViewModel> RangeCalibrationControlViewModels;`

and in NewScaleCalibrationDialog I would normally do this (and this works):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RangeCalibrationControlViewModels}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NewScaleRangeCalibrationControl}" />
```

But I want to use transitioner like this (this doesn't work):

```
<materialDesign:Transitioner ItemsSource="{Binding RangeCalibrationControlViewModels}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NewScaleRangeCalibrationControl}" />
```

Can be this madewith Transitioner or it is possible only with ItemsControl? I want every slide in Transitioner to be 1 control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out myself. It can be done, I just forgot to put SelectedIndex="0" in XAML

```
<materialDesign:Transitioner SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding RangeCalibrationControlViewModels}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NewScaleRangeCalibrationControl}" />
```

Also, if you want to navigate through tabs, just add button command for next and previous slide in the control.